# Wordpress - What is the regular expression for uploads directory while editing the database file?

Tags: regex, wordpress

For some reason I re-uploaded all my media through Wordpress Media Uploader, hence, whatever, I have uploaded is in `/uploads/2018/04` directory. However, in database, I have entries like `/uploads/2018/03`, `/uploads/2017/03`, `/uploads/2016/03` and etc. I have the sql file of my database and now I want to search for all the places like `/uploads/year/month` and replace them with `/uploads/2018/04`. How am I supposed to do that using regular expression for search and replace in any code editor?

Comment: If you don't show your efforts, this is going to be an off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may search for the following pattern:

```
/uploads/\d{4}/\d{2}
```

and replace with:

```
/uploads/2018/04
```

Depending on the editor you are using, you may also have to escape the forward slashes, in which case you would search for this instead:

```
\/uploads\/\d{4}\/\d{2}
```